# a problem in functional analysis that erdos solved in 2 lines

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, reference-request

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/261685/paul-erdoss-two-line-functional-analysis-proof .

does anyone know about what the problem was and what was his solution.

[Edit by quid:] please follow the link before trying to answer, there is already quite a bit of relevant information behind the link. [End edit]

Comment: May be that was a half-page proof that $\pi$ is transcendental using $\Gamma$-functions?

Comment: @Victor: Does proving $\pi$ to be transcendental involve functional analysis?


Comment: Well, if you admit that $\Gamma$-functions is a part of functional analysis, then "yes". I remember when I first learnt about that proof -- which is really ad hoc argument -- I was overexcited and thought that it seems like beautiful Erdos-type proofs.

Comment: @Victor: Hmmm..I would rather consider $\Gamma$-functions as part of real analysis than Functional Analysis.


Comment: The transcendence of $\pi$ is due to to Bryant?

Comment: Dear Koushik, if you had added more context to the question, we could have avoided some unnecessary speculation among the commenters who didn't bother to click through.

Comment: This should be closed in favor of the stack exchange question, in light of the quality of the answers there.  It's hard to do much better than have the actual source of the anecdote answer.

Comment: This should absolutely *not* be closed, because we still don't know what the problem was, much less P.E.'s solution! The information given at mathstackexchange was curiously and frustratingly incomplete. 

Comment: @todd, that's also what I think.I am curious to know how a 30 page solution can be reduced to 2 lines.

Comment: @Todd Trimble: I did not yet vote to close but the way this is presented here is rather bad relative to math.SE. Also, there is given quite a clear lead to a possibly definitive answer; perhaps somebody well-placed to do so should just restart the process on math.SE or follow the lead directly.  @Koushik: Why is that even so surprising? The really surprising thing is that it was done (supposedly) "on the spot". 

Comment: Well, okay quid, but still let's keep this open. It couldn't hurt to ask here too, since more people will thereby see the question and can answer here and/or there. (Small rant: I wish more popular accounts of mathematicians would give precise information along with all the gushing and apotheosizing! One thing I appreciated about Nasar's A Beautiful Mind is that she made some attempt to actually state theorems -- even if there is some slight garbling here and there, it still heightened my appreciation of what Nash actually did.) 

Answer (score 1):

Hi
   In 'The man who loved only numbers'by Paul Hoffman relates the story on page 49, but there is no mention of the actual problem or solution. The story was retold by George Purdy of Texas A & M.

Ron Hallam

Comment: This is not really your fault (but the questioners), yet this and quite a bit more is already documented behind the link; even George Purdy himself commented there.  

Comment: both problem much less the solution is given there.i may be very much possible that someone here might be knowing that.